# /bin/launchctl problem on start mysql after upgrade to 12.4

Tags: homebrew, launchd, monterey, mysql

I upgrade my OSX to 12.4. after that my brew mysql don't start.

I got:

```
$ brew services start mysql
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/gerd/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` exited with 5.
```

I think it's a permission problem. The brew mysql stop by root on upgrade to 12.4

```
brew services list
Name       Status  User      File
mysql      stopped root      ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem of OSX permission for network connections. The mysqld need this permission. After finsh install 12.4 and restart, the mysqld don't have this permission! Perhaps, it was my mistake and I click the wrong button on a OSX permission dialog.

I rebooted 12.4 and after login I got the OSX permission dialog for mysqld. I granted network access. After it mysqld work fine!

Comment: I have the same issue, how can I give permission to the mysqld?

Comment: You got the permission dialog from OSX after reboot. Try a reboot of your system!